# Linux:How create specify file?

Tags: linux, shell

I get some data source by columns command:

```
a aaa
b bbb
...
z zzz
```

expect:

create **a.txt**,**b.txt** ... **z.txt** file,the file content is `aaa`,`bbb`...`zzz`.

Comment: I konw > command, but fail.

Comment: `awk '{print >> $1".txt"; close ($1".txt")}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that the data you provided are stored in a file with name  "data.file", this one works ok for me:

```
datasource=$(cat data.file)

while IFS='' read -r line; do
filename=$(cut -f 1 -d " " <<<$line)
contents=$(cut -f 2 -d " " <<<$line)
echo "$contents" > "$filename"
done <<< "$datasource"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use grep, that may work for your case, for example:

```
grep "^a\s" file > a.txt
grep "^b\s" file > b.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But I get many rows, not only two rows.

Comment: Please post your script, the input data, the output you get, and the output you expect.